# How to make a listview.builder update in realtime after filtering the list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a StreamBuilder where the stream is bookings, I have a TableCalendar that when Clicked will update the Listview with a new filtered list of bookings made only on that date,The issue is when a user ads a new bookings the stream gets updated but since we rely on a button click in the TableCalendar to update the Listivew, the listview won't get automatically updated when a new booking is added, is there a way to fix this?

```
class _AdminHomePageState extends ConsumerState<AdminHomePage> {
  CalendarFormat _calendarFormat = CalendarFormat.month;
  DateTime _focusedDay = DateTime.now();
  DateTime _selectedDay = DateTime.now();
  DBHandler dbhandler = DBHandler();
  List<Booking> allBookings = [];
  List<Booking> filteredBooking = [];

//now i neeed a selected events where it returns events for a certain day when clciked
  Map<DateTime, List<Booking>> events = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
 
  }

  List<Booking> filterBookingsByDate(
      DateTime selectedDate, List<Booking> unfiltered) {
    List<Booking> filteredBookings = [];

    for (var booking in unfiltered) {
      if (isSameDay(booking.bookingDate, selectedDate)) {
        filteredBookings.add(booking);
      }
    }

    return filteredBookings;
  }

  //need a method here to get bookings for a particular Date
  //I can interate thourhg the Bookings list trying to match the bookingDate to selectedDay

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bookingsAsyncValue = ref.watch(bookingsProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Bookings'),
      ),
      body: bookingsAsyncValue.when(
        data: (bookings) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 300,
                    child: TableCalendar(
                      firstDay: DateTime.utc(2010, 10, 16),
                      lastDay: DateTime.utc(2030, 3, 14),
                      focusedDay: DateTime.now(),
                      calendarFormat: _calendarFormat,
                      calendarStyle:
                          const CalendarStyle(outsideDaysVisible: false),
                      onFormatChanged: (format) {
                        setState(() {
                          _calendarFormat = format;
                        });
                      },
                      selectedDayPredicate: (day) {
                        return isSameDay(_selectedDay, day);
                      },
                      onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedDay = selectedDay;
                          _focusedDay =
                              focusedDay; // Update focused day as well
                          filteredBooking =
                              filterBookingsByDate(selectedDay, bookings);
                          //ChatGpt here you should show the bookings that have a startDate on the selected day

                          //use the Selected Day to get List of bookings below
                        });
                      },
                      onPageChanged: (focusedDay) {
                        _focusedDay = focusedDay;
                      },
                      eventLoader: (day) {
                        // Remove the time information from the day parameter
                        DateTime dateOnly =
                            DateTime(day.year, day.month, day.day);
                        return events[dateOnly] ?? [];
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 300,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: filteredBooking.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final booking = filteredBooking[index];
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(booking.serviceTitle),
                        subtitle: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text('Email: ${booking.userEmail}'),
                            Text(
                                'Date: ${DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(booking.bookingDate)}'),
                            Text(
                                'StartTime: ${DateFormat('HH:mm').format(booking.startTime)}'),
                          ],
                        ),
                        // Add more widgets to display other booking details
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
        loading: () {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
        error: (error, stackTrace) {
          return Center(
            child: Text('Error: $error'),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use state management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest you not to use setState and riverpod for managing state in a same widget. Try to extract widgets if possible.

You can achieve the desired featured by creating the filteredList inside the build() method.

Remove

```
List<Booking> filteredBooking = [];
```

from your state variable and add this in your build Method.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

final bookingsAsyncValue = ref.watch(bookingsProvider);

final filteredBooking = filterBookingsByDate(_selectedDay, allBookings);
```

Comment: That completely makes senes thank, just curious why it's bad to use riverpod and setState in the same widget? does it make it slower?

Comment: Using both setState and Riverpod (or any other state management) in the same widget is not recommended. It can make your code less clear and harder to maintain. Sticking with one approach, like Riverpod, helps keep your code clean and easy to work with.

Additionally, while it might not necessarily slow down your app, it can lead to unnecessary re-renders or updates, potentially impacting performance if not managed carefully.

Comment: Should I make a new provider for every variable I update in SetState